# Glassfish v3 cache and Varnish cached

Tags: glassfish, varnish

I am looking into way to speed up my site, which contain a decent amount of small images at one times (so my site primary does IO read). I use glassfish v3. In GF v3, I specify glassfish to cache static resources. Is it sufficient to just use GF cache? Will varnish cache will me significant improvement over GF cache? **Do GF work well with varnish?**

Answer (score 1):

Varnish may be a better option; rather than trying to manage it's own set of files in memory and on-disk, it works to utilize the underlying caching system of the OS itself instead of fighting against it, which is why it often out-performs other caching technologies such as Squid.

I've found Varnish to be very simple to set-up and have used it in the past to help a number of client sites survive "slashdottings".

Comment: have you ever set varnish to run with Glassfish v3?

Comment: No, but I would stop GlassFish from handling static resources and give that job to Varnish; it will be better at managing them. I'd also try and use Varnish to reverse-proxy/cache GlassFish dynamic content (where possible) to get an extra speed bump.

Comment: Is it hard to do `reverse-proxy/cache GlassFish dynamic content (where possible) to get an extra speed bump`? Can u point me to some tutorial that show me how? Thank you

Comment: Just put your GlassFish server on a different port than port 80 (eg. 8080), put Varnish on port 80, then point it to your GlassFish server. The Varnish docs are quite good - best to start there. :)

Answer (score 1):

Varnish is tested against Apache Traffic Server (also a cache server), Nginx and Lighttpd here:

http://nbonvin.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/serving-small-static-files-which-server-to-use/

The charts are showing CPU and memory consumption as well as the performances.